# Не могу передать данные input type file с JS в PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Есть форма, 90% формы обрабатывается php, поле с вложениями обрабатывается js, так как заказчик хочет видеть и редактировать аттачи перед отправкой. При удалении аттача - файлы не приходят, php выдает ошибку 4, если отправлять как есть, не редактируя - все ок.

Расписываю более подробно:
В JS я не особо силен, поэтому мое понимание js который используется у меня - вполне может быть некорректным
 При помощи js я получаю список аттачей с input type files. Так как этот список в DOM доступен только для чтения - для того чтобы его изменить я делаю копию этого списка аттачей, в отдельный объект, его правлю и дальше как-то должен отправить(пробовал реализовать отправку через FormData) а сам инпут очищаю - это судя по тому коду js который я использую. При вардампе $_FILES мне приходят данные с формы за исключением input type file. Как я писал выше, массив $_FILES выдает ошибку 4. 
Вот ссылка на полную версию этого вопроса, который люто заминусовали.
[Ссылка на зря заминусованный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912180/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B)
 Редактирование аттачей делал отсюда
[ТЫК!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062876/removing-file-from-multiple-files-uploader-on-button-click-when-using-html5-file)

в php файлы принимаю так:

```
$filess = $_FILES;
    var_dump($filess);
    foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $value){
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
        var_dump($filename);
        $file = fopen($filename, "rb");
        $data = fread($file,  filesize( $filename ) );
        fclose($file);
        $NameFile = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key]; // в этой переменной надо сформировать имя файла (без всякого пути);
        $File = $data;
        $multipart .=  "$EOL--$boundary$EOL";   
        $multipart .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$NameFile\"$EOL";   
        $multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64$EOL";   
        $multipart .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$NameFile\"$EOL";   
        $multipart .= $EOL; // раздел между заголовками и телом прикрепленного файла 
        $multipart .= chunk_split(base64_encode($File));   
   }
```

Подозреваю что у меня либо с фронта не отправляются данные(хотя в консоли я вижу их), либо в php неправильно их принимаю. Подскажите пожалуйста что не так.

Comment: Непонятно, что вы спрашиваете. Что значит "поле с вложениями обрабатывается js"? Так или иначе набор аттачей приходит вам на сервер. Что показывает `var_dump($filess);`? Приходят файлы какие-то или нет?

Comment: @u_mulder - добавил правки в вопрос, если нужно - могу предоставить все исходники и ответить на все возникающие вопросы.

Comment: >>>> При помощи js я получаю список аттачей с input type files.
Откуда получаете?
>>>> для того чтобы его изменить 
Что подразумеваете под изменением?

Comment: @Ofer - получаю  с инпута. input type="file" - хранит в себе список всех выбранных для отправки файлов.Под изменеием я подразумеваю следующее: Присоединяю к примеру 4 файла, присоединил, вывелся список файлов которые я добавил, смотрю - 1 лишний, я его удаляю, (предполагается что возле каждого файла кнопка с крестиком будет) - и потом отправляю уже новый список аттачей.

Comment: Тогда копировать вам ничего не надо. Просто удалили input из DOM структуры и он отправляться уже не будет.

Comment: @Ofer не совсем понял Вашу мысль, если я удалю инпут - то по идее удаляется список аттачей, даже если вы имели ввиду сделать копию этого списка а потом удалить инпут - то стоит вопрос отправки скопированых данных на сервер (я пробовал через FormData) - не вышло.